# Questions to create a nested list retrieved from an XML-file and displayed in xHTML

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xmlhttprequest

The objective is to display a list of URLs in an HTML page. The list is retrieved from another file (currently in XML-format).

1. Validator: What is the proper xHTML mark-up for a list generated by JavaScript and still validate properly?
   I assume the reason is that JavaScript-code inside [ul]'s is not accepted. Is this correct? Is there another solution?
   The code below does produce the list anticipated, but it creates a warning (pls see below, 2.).

   ```
   <ul>list A
   <li>item A1</li>
   <li>item A2</li>        
   <ul>List B
       <li>item B1</li>
       <script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */
           if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
               {  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  } // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari                        
           else
               {  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  }       // code for IE6, IE5    
           xmlhttp.open("GET","/test-code/panorama-list2.xml",false);
           //  xmlhttp.open("GET","/test-code/panorama-list2.xml",true);   //this does not work. xmlDoc is null.
           xmlhttp.send();

           xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
           var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");
           for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
           {   document.write('<li class="menu2">'+'<a href="');
               document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName('link')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
               document.write('">');
               document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName('description')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
               document.write('</li>');    }       
           //]]></script>      //This is line: 136
   </ul>
   ```
2. The JavaScript used in the code above is called using the synchronous method and thus creating the Warning: 
   "An unbalanced tree was written using document.write() causing data from the network to be reparsed. For more information https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Optimizing_Your_Pages_for_Speculative_Parsing
   / Source File: /test-code/index2.htm / Line: 136"

The solution is to use the asynchronous method similar to the code below placed into the  section.
The solution is NOT to simply setting 'true' in the function xmlhttp.open (..., ..., true);.

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
function loadXMLDoc()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  }   // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
else
  {  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  }     // code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)

    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
      var txt = "";
      var txt1 = "";
      var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");

      for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
      {
        txt = x[i].getElementsByTagName('description')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br />";
        txt1 = x[i].getElementsByTagName('link')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br />";
      }

    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=txt;
    document.getElementById("myDiv1").innerHTML=txt1;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","panorama-list2.xml",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
//]]></script>
```

That does take care of the Warning.
I assume a solution would be to combine these 2 examples of code.

That's what I am trying:
The Variables 'txt' and 'txt1' retrieve the last entry of the XML-file.

How do I get all entires as well? The amount of entries varies.

Here is the big question:

How can I create a proper list using the asynchronous method and obtain a result like in the initial code example where the list is generated by stepping through the XML-file? 
After all, is there is another, better or simpler solution? The file with data for the list shall not be part of the xHTML mark-up.

At last an actual page using the initial code example. The list is revealed by hovering over the button at top-right: http://www.halo-photographs.com/2011-Cascata-da-Bernina/index.htm (yes, this is my own page) 
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Have you considered XSLT to transform your XML in XHTML and then insert it in the DOM?

Comment: Yes, I did but started out with JavaScript. Would an XSL-Transformation be more feasible as a solution for this?  The generated list is rather small (about 20 to max 30 entries) and the only data that is not part of the mark-up.

Comment: You need a combination of both: get the xml, transform it using xslt, and insert it in the DOM, all this with Javascript

Comment: Can you change the message from the server and get a JSON instead?

Comment: @Mic get xml, transform it and insert to DOM Hm, sounds good, guess I give it a try.  Change message: I don't know. What message?

Comment: I meant changing what you receive from the server if you can. From XML to JSON. I've used XML for years, and now JSON and wouldn't like to come back again to XML. JSON is way simpler to manipulate in the browser and lighter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you code is an soup..

you need refactor that

now with jquery

in the load the you page

you should put somthing how that

```
$(document).ready(function(){    

 BeforePrepareList();

}); 

function BeforePrepareList()
{
  var xmlRequest = XmlHttpRequestResolver();

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
                   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)

                   var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
                   // you need parse string response a array or use xslt, the next
                   // is simple for each
                   ListSetting(xmlDoc);
               }
   xmlhttp.open("GET","panorama-list2.xml",true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}

function XmlHttpRequestResolver()
{
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   return xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  else
   return xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");     // code for IE6, IE5
}

function ListSetting(rawdata)
{     
  ListPopulate($("_PUT_YOUR_LIST_ID_HERE").get(0), rawdata);        
}


function ListPopulate(el, items) {
  el.options.length = 0;
  if (items.length > 0)
     el.options[0] = new Option('All', '');

  // THAT IS AN SIMPLE EXAMPLE, CHANGE FOR CREATE tag <a />
  $.each(items, function (index,item) {
    el.options[el.options.length] = new Option(item.[PROPERTY_A], item.[PROPERTY_B]);
 });    
}

and .....
```

more information here

invoke xml and transform http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-ffox3/index.html
examples de http request http://www.jibbering.com/2002/4/httprequest.html

Comment: You're right about 'code soup' and thanks for the links provided - they do help. Meanwhile I finished the soup and the code pretty much reflects your suggestion above. I you wish check out the near final pages at http://tiny.cc/xdlly (yes, this is my own page, the uri as provided above).

Comment: One important question remains open for me: I apply an XSLT to the XML-file and the output is exactly that list I want. But the XMLHTTPRequest delivers unformatted raw data. Is there a way to make use of the formatted XML-XSLT-Data?

Comment: Here it is: http://tiny.cc/lsnvg  The xml and the output generated with an xsl (look inside the XML). I think with PHP5 I can accomplish my goal (probably easier than with JS or jQ).

Comment: Also look at the solution in JS that I've got so far: tiny.cc/xdlly (same uri as in the initial question, but code is totally rewritten).

Comment: you can accomplish with jquery look at http://www.compoc.com/tuts/ and two important points in that tutorial $('student',xml).each (for each in branch of xml) and $(#ContentArea").append (let add html content on an html tag)